# I can not deploy react app on github pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

```
> facerecognitionbrain@0.1.0 predeploy D:\Web Design Backup Files\face-recogniti
on-app
> npm run build


> facerecognitionbrain@0.1.0 build D:\Web Design Backup Files\face-recognition-a
pp
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.

File sizes after gzip:

  62.14 KB  build\static\js\1.b8657c84.chunk.js
  12.85 KB  build\static\css\1.92aa9987.chunk.css
  5.88 KB   build\static\js\main.8941c490.chunk.js
  776 B     build\static\js\runtime~main.6de2bf8d.js
  621 B     build\static\css\main.1e11d24f.chunk.css

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /face-recognition-app/.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
To publish it at https://iamtheasad.github.io/face-recognition-app, run:

  npm run deploy

Find out more about deployment here:



> facerecognitionbrain@0.1.0 deploy D:\Web Design Backup Files\face-recognition-
app
> gh-pages -d build

fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: RPC failed; curl 55 OpenSSL SSL_write: SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN, errno 10053

Everything up-to-date
```

> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>       npm ERR! errno 1
>       npm ERR! facerecognitionbrain@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
>       npm ERR! Exit status 1
>       npm ERR!
>       npm ERR! Failed at the facerecognitionbrain@0.1.0 deploy script.
>       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
>       ging output above.
>
> ```
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Rana\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-01T17_51_58_0
> 63Z-debug.log
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a problem with your local git configuration or caused by some bad network status or some large files included in your commit. In my case, I have tried after some mins, it worked.

So I suggest you should do push several times in some intervals, or increase buffer size and then try to push again?

git config --global http.postBuffer 15728640

Comment: Hi Sean Kelly,
It was the problem of my git configuration.
Thanks for your help.